# Errno 13 Permission denied error when trying to export graph with Networkx library

Tags: python, windows, pandas, networkx

I am trying to export a graphml using this code:

```
nx.write_graphml(G, 'C:/Users/my_name/documents')
```

And i am getting this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-4588884f9b0a> in <module>()
----> 1 nx.write_graphml(G, 'C:/Users/my_name/Documents')

<decorator-gen-324> in write_graphml(G, path, encoding, prettyprint)

C:\Users\my_name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py in _open_file(func, *args, **kwargs)
    196         if is_string_like(path):
    197             ext = splitext(path)[1]
--> 198             fobj = _dispatch_dict[ext](path, mode=mode)
    199             close_fobj = True
    200         elif hasattr(path, 'read'):

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

I did find some other people that have encountered the same error in a different context but I can't seem to find a solution.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Usually I do run into this error when I can have the output file still opened in other application on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed a folder to the function, it needs to be a file name, see documentation of [write_graphml](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.graphml.write_graphml.html). So, you can change your code like this, for example:

```
nx.write_graphml(G, 'C:/Users/my_name/Documents/my_graph.graphml')
```

Comment: Ty, that was the issue. I realised it 20 seconds ago and I feel pretty embarrassed.

Comment: No worries, happens to the best of us :)